# How should one approach this PDE's?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have got two tasks with PDE's and I am not really familiar with them, so I have no idea, how to approach this kind of problems.

**First:** Solve the following PDE:$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial  t} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial ^2 x}, u(t,0)=u(t, \pi), u(0,x)= \sin x \cos ^2 x$$

**Second:** Solve the following PDE: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial  t} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial ^2 x} ,u(t,0)=u(t, \pi)=1, u(0,x)=\cos^2x+\sin^2x(1+\sin2x)$$

And the same task, but now with $$\partial u(t,0)/\partial x = \partial u(t, \pi)/\partial x=0, u(0,x)=\cos^2x+\sin^2x(1+\cos2x)$$

I looked up how should one approach these kinds of tasks, and I found, that I should assume, that $u=e^{ax+bt}$, and then calculate $u_t, u_x, u_{xx}$, which are $e^{ax+bt}*b, e^{ax+bt}*a, e^{ax+bt}*a^2$. So if $u_t=u_{xx}$, then $b=a^2$.

I would appreciate any help, thanks for anyone!

Comment: These are boundary value problems for the one dimensional heat equation. The solutions can be quite long and in several steps but can be found in most engineering maths books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial  t} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial ^2 x}, \quad \begin{cases}u(t,0)=u(t, \pi)\\ u(0,x)= \sin x \cos ^2 x =\frac{1}{4}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{4}\sin(3x)  \end{cases}$$
With the method of separation of variables, we look for particular solutions on the form $u=f(t)g(x)$ so that $g(x)$ be on the form $\sin(nx)$ according to the form of the boundary conditions.

$$f'g=fg'' \quad\to\quad \frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g''}{g}=-n^2 \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases} g(x)=\sin(nx) \\ f(t)=e^{-n^2t} \end{cases}$$
$$  u_n(t,x)=C_ne^{-n^2t}\sin(nx)$$

$\begin{cases}u_n(t,0)=C_ne^{-n^2t}\sin(n0)=0 \\ u_n(t,\pi)=C_ne^{-n^2t}\sin(n\pi)=0\end{cases}\quad$ Hense the condition  $u(t,0)=u(t, \pi)$ is satisfied.

Then the sum of two particular solutions, with $n=1$ and $n=3$ provides the solution according to the condition $u(0,x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{4}\sin(3x)$ with $C_1=C_3=\frac{1}{4}$
$$u(t,x)=\frac{1}{4}e^{-t}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{4}e^{-9t}\sin(3x) $$

Try a similar approach for the second problem. In case of trouble, explain where exactly the difficulty arises.

Hint : A simplification occurs, especially in the boundary conditions, with the change of function $$u(t,x)=v(t,x)+1$$

Comment: Can I ask how you got $\frac14 \sin(x)+\frac14 \sin(3x)$ ? :)

Comment: I am having difficulties making these kind of identities at the start. :) How should I simplify in the second task with $\cos^2x+ \sin^2x(1+\sin 2x)$?

Comment: In the first task : $$\sin(x)\cos^2(x)= \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^2$$ Expanding it and after simplification leads to : $$=\frac{e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}+e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{8i}$$ $$=\frac{\sin(3x)}{4}+\frac{\sin(x)}{4}$$ In the second task, what do you obtain from $\sin^2(x)\sin(2x)$ ?

Comment: I got $\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}-\frac{\sin(4x)}{4}$ :)

Comment: Right. Now you can write down the new PDE and conditions with $v(t,x)$.